# How to get Windows Message in background by C++

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, winapi, visual-c++

I need to get Windows Message in background.
I tried to use Message-Only Window, but it doesn't work.
I only found it works when Window is "visable" and "focus" status.
Please help me, thank you very much!

#### Windows Message example

```cpp
#define WM_KEYFIRST                     0x0100
#define WM_KEYDOWN                      0x0100
#define WM_KEYUP                        0x0101
#define WM_CHAR                         0x0102
#define WM_DEADCHAR                     0x0103
#define WM_SYSKEYDOWN                   0x0104
#define WM_SYSKEYUP                     0x0105
#define WM_SYSCHAR                      0x0106
#define WM_SYSDEADCHAR                  0x0107
```

#### codes for message-only window

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>

using namespace std;

namespace {
    LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProcedure(HWND hWnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
    {

        std::cout << "INFO: " << __func__ << ": WndProc: message= 0x" << std::hex << uMsg << ", wParam = 0x" << std::hex << wParam << "\n";
        if (uMsg == WM_COPYDATA)
            std::cout << "Got a message!" << std::endl;
        return DefWindowProc(hWnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
    }
}

int main()
{
    WNDCLASS windowClass = {};
    windowClass.lpfnWndProc = WindowProcedure;
    LPCWSTR windowClassName = L"FoobarMessageOnlyWindow";
    windowClass.lpszClassName = windowClassName;

    if (!RegisterClass(&windowClass)) {
        std::cout << "Failed to register window class" << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    HWND messageWindow = CreateWindowEx(0, windowClassName, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, HWND_MESSAGE, 0, 0, 0);
    //HWND messageWindow = GetDesktopWindow();
    cout << "INFO: " << __func__ << " CreateWindow messageWindow=" << messageWindow << "\n";
    if (!messageWindow) {
        std::cout << "Failed to create message-only window" << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    MSG msg;
    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0) > 0) {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }
    return msg.wParam;
}
```

#### logs:

```
INFO: WindowProcedure: WndProc: message= 0x24, wParam = 0x0
INFO: WindowProcedure: WndProc: message= 0x81, wParam = 0x0
INFO: WindowProcedure: WndProc: message= 0x83, wParam = 0x0
INFO: WindowProcedure: WndProc: message= 0x1, wParam = 0x0
INFO: main CreateWindow messageWindow=00000000005B0E42
```

Comment: Scrap all your debugging output. It doesn't show meaningful values anywhere. [GetLastError](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/errhandlingapi/nf-errhandlingapi-getlasterror) returns meaningful values only at very specific points, detailed in the respective API documentation. Any interleaving code will turn the result meaningless. `cout << "trash my error diagnostics, plz. kthx"` totally will. That aside, what problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: Oops! sorry... I am a newbie for programing, I just want to write a console app and this app can recieve windows message.

Comment: Please read [ask].

Comment: The *Windows Message example* lists keyboard messages. The code checks for `WM_COPYDATA`. There is no overlap between them. Discovering either one(s) has different solutions. Which one are you looking for? More importantly, why do you need to discover those messages? What are you going to do with that information?

Comment: Keyboard messages are sent only to the window that has input focus. Hidden and message-only windows don't apply for that. If you want to capture keyboard input in the background, you have to use a keyboard hook via `SetWindowsHookEx()`, or the Raw Input API via `RegisterRawInputDevices()`. If you want to capture messages for someone else's window, use a message hook via `SetWindowsHookEx()`

Comment: Sorry for unclear description.Actually, I like to recieve Window Message, and it also works when Window is visable and focus. But I don't know how to recieve Windows Message in the background. Anyway, thanks for your information. I will continue to try it. The Window Message is like below: `UINT MY_WM_MESSAGE = RegisterWindowMessage(_T("MY WM Message"));  
ChangeWindowMessageFilterEx(hWnd, MY_WM_MESSAGE, MSGFLT_ALLOW, NULL);`

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your advices, finally, I found we could use CreateWindowEx() and just keep Window invisible to get Window Message I need in background. About getting key event in backgroud, we could use RegisterHotKey().

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <atlstr.h>

using namespace std;

#define MAX_LOADSTRING 100

TCHAR szTitle[MAX_LOADSTRING] = TEXT("TEST TITLE");
TCHAR szWindowClass[MAX_LOADSTRING] = TEXT("TEST WindowClass");

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    std::cout << "INFO: " << __func__ << ": WndProc: message= 0x" << std::hex << message << ", wParam = 0x" << std::hex << wParam << "\n";

    return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
}

ATOM MyRegisterClass(HINSTANCE hInstance)
{
    WNDCLASSEX wcex;

    wcex.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    wcex.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    wcex.lpfnWndProc = WndProc;
    wcex.cbClsExtra = 0;
    wcex.cbWndExtra = 0;
    wcex.hInstance = hInstance;
    wcex.hIcon = LoadIcon(hInstance, NULL);
    wcex.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wcex.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW + 1);
    wcex.lpszMenuName = NULL;
    wcex.lpszClassName = szWindowClass;
    wcex.hIconSm = LoadIcon(wcex.hInstance, NULL);

    ATOM ret = RegisterClassEx(&wcex);

    return ret;
}

BOOL InitInstance(HINSTANCE hInstance)
{
    HWND hWnd;

    hWnd = CreateWindowEx(0, szWindowClass, szTitle, WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
        CW_USEDEFAULT, 0, CW_USEDEFAULT, 0, NULL, NULL, hInstance, NULL);
    if (!hWnd)
    {
        return FALSE;
    }

    return TRUE;
}

int main()
{
    MSG msg;
    HINSTANCE hInstance = GetModuleHandleA(NULL);

    MyRegisterClass(hInstance);

    if (!InitInstance(hInstance))
    {
        return FALSE;
    }

    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> I tried to use Message-Only Window, but it doesn't work.

You need to understand the real use of message-only window.

From [Message-Only Windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/window-features#message-only-windows),

> A message-only window enables you to send and receive messages. It is
> not visible, has no z-order, cannot be enumerated, and does not
> receive broadcast messages. The window simply dispatches messages.

In other words, you can send messages (`PostMessage` and `SendMessage`) to it.

Like this,

```
SendMessage(messageWindow,WM_CHAR, (WPARAM)0x41, (LPARAM)0);
```

then,

[image]

Benefits of using a message only window,

- Free queue for messages.

> If your system is message based from some sort of external IO say, and
> you are in need of a queuing facility, then your application can use
> PostMessage to post messages to the hidden window. These messages will
> be queued in the normal Windows message queue.

- Inter/intra process communication

> Another part of your application (or an external application) can
> handle the arrival of these messages.

If you want to monitor Windows Message in background(Third-party GUI Application), you can follow @Remy's suggestions.

Comment: @CodeLamb Hi, please tell me if the answer is useful to you.

Comment: Hi Strive, thanks for your feedback. But I found I only could get Windows Message by `CreateWindowEx()`. For details, please refer to my anwser.